# Search a 2D table with variables and find their intersection value

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

So I have a 2D table of data (letters & variables plotted against each other) and am trying to search both the axis with values taken from a simple 3 column table (letter,variable,value) and find the intersecting value and print it in the value col of the simple table.

A snapshot of my tables are below:

[image]

I can do it by hard coding the values in but am struggling to get it working with variables since im kinda new to using VBA. The working hard coded version is below:

```
Sub Finder()
    Dim var As String
    Dim ltr As String
    var = Range("T2").value
    ltr = Range("S2").value

    Dim variable As String
    Dim letter As String

    Dim col As Range
    Dim row As Range

    variable = var
    letter = ltr

    Set col = Range("A1:AAA1").Find(what:=variable).EntireColumn
    Set row = Range("A2:A100").Find(what:=letter).EntireRow

    Dim value As String
    MsgBox Intersect(col, row).value
    Range("U2") = Intersect(col, row).value
End Sub
```

My current code that im trying to do same with variables is below:

```
Sub Finder()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngltr As Range
    Dim rngvar As Range
    Dim rngval As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dcol As Range
    Dim drow As Range
    Dim row As Range

    Dim var As String
    Dim ltr As String
    Dim val As String

    Set rng = Range("tblValues")
    Set rngltr = rng.Columns(1)
    Set rngvar = rng.Columns(2)
    Set rngval = rng.Columns(3)

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            ltr = Range(row).Columns(1).value
            var = Range(row).Columns(2).value
            val = Range(row).Columns(3).value
            'row.Interior.Color = vbYellow

            Set dcol = Range("A1:AAA1").Find(what:=var).EntireColumn
            Set drow = Range("A2:A100").Find(what:=ltr).EntireRow

            Dim value As String
            MsgBox Intersect(dcol, drow).value
            Range(row).Columns(3) = Intersect(dcol, drow).value
        Next cell
    Next row
End Sub
```

in the hard coded version it works perfectly but with adding the complexity of a loop to go row by row and the variables I think I'm on the right track but I'm not too sure at the same time. 
Any advice or pointers on what way I should to approach this or if I am doing this completely wrong could someone point me in the right direction,

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of your table?

Comment: @Zac Added a screenshot

Comment: You can use INDEX and MATCH formulae for this, no need for VBA.

Comment: This is a small sample to test but when scaled I'll be using it on thousands of rows, I was under the impression Index Match will take too long. Also doing it in VBA and not excel as its part of a wider process, its just one element of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, try this. It's only necessary to loop through one column of your table and reference other columns using OFFSET.

```
Sub Finder()

Dim rng As ListObject, rng1 As Range
Dim dcol As Range
Dim drow As Range
Dim row As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblValues")
Set rng1 = rng.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange 'easier to refer to table ranges in this way I think

For Each row In rng1 'loop through first column of tblValues
    Set dcol = Range("A1:AAA1").Find(what:=row.Offset(, 1))
    Set drow = Range("A2:A100").Find(what:=row)
    If Not dcol Is Nothing And Not drow Is Nothing Then 'always check values are found to avoid errors
        MsgBox Intersect(dcol.EntireColumn, drow.EntireRow).value
        row.Offset(, 2) = Intersect(dcol.EntireColumn, drow.EntireRow).value
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver SJR, was messing around with it for 2 days now but this work perfectly. Thank You